# Is this set open or closed

Tags: general-topology

Is $(-1,0]\cup[0,1)$ open or closed, both or neither (relative to R)?

This set doesn't contain the limit point $1$, so it's not closed. But how can I determine whether it's open or not? The complement is $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$, but I can't seem to figure out whether it's closed or not. I would say it's closed because it contains every point, so that would make $(-1,0]\cup[0,1)$ an open set, but the infinity thing kinda sets me off.

Comment: Isn't the set same as $(-1,1)$?

Comment: $(-1,0]\cup [0,1)=(-1,1)$ is open.

Comment: @Gatuam Shenoy, yes it is

Comment: Do you mean $(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$?

Comment: My mistake, fixed it. However, I'm still struggling with the infinity thing. @Laars Helenius, could you tell me how you came up with that?

Comment: $(-1,1)$ is open because it is a bounded interval that doesn't contain the limit points $-1$ or $1$.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius, but a set not being closed doesn't imply it being open, does it?

Comment: That's correct. I misspoke. $(-1,1)$ doesn't contain any of it boundary points and hence is open.

Comment: "Most" subsets of $\Bbb R$ are neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(-1,0]\cup[0,1)=(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The set A is closed when for any sequence $x_n\in A$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n} \in A$$

too.

So you can say easily $(-\infty,+\infty)$ is open. the same as $(1,\infty)$ and $(-1,+1)$

In all one-segment-sets, `(` or `)` means open.

Comment: How is $[1,\infty)$ open? It doesn't have an $\epsilon$-neighborbood around 1.

Answer (score 0):

If unsure, go back to definitions:
$$(-1,0]\cup[0,1)=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid -1\lt x \leq 0\}\cup \{x\in\mathbb R\mid 0\leq x\lt 1\}=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid -1\lt x \leq 0 \,\land 0\leq x\lt 1\}=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid -1\lt x \lt 1\}=(-1,1)$$
Which is open in $\mathbb R$ (with the usual topology).

Why is it open?
Show the complement of your interval in $\mathbb R$ i.e. $(-1,1)^c=(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)$ is closed. It is if(f) it contains all its limit points. Does it?

Comment: *You can find a sequence in the interval* $(-1,1)$ *whose limit is not in the interval.* —this only means that this interval is not closed, not that it is open.

Comment: That there is a sequence in the interval which doesn't have a limit in the interval doesn't mean that the set isn't open.

Comment: Brain-fart. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ is defined in your course, but in a metric space (of which $\mathbb{R}$ is an example), a set is open if for each point of the set there is a ball of finite radius around the point contained within the set.

So open intervals $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ are open, because for any $x_0 \in (a,b)$, the ball of radius $\min\left(\frac{x_0-a}{2},\frac{b-x_0}{2}\right)$ is contained in $(a,b)$ (draw a picture and you'll see what this means).

Then you just have to realize that $(-1,0]\cup[0,1)$ is the same set as $(-1,1)$.